# jCarousel slider shows items more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a newbie to javascript. I am trying to implement a simple slider to my website. 
My html configuration is:

```
<div>
    <ul id="mainSlider">
        <li>
            <img src="img/slideImg.png" alt="Slide" class="slideImage fl">
            <h1>Web Development</h1>
            <p class="slideParagraph">
            Web development is a broad term for the work involved in developing
            a web site for the Internet (World Wide Web) or an intranet.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="darkButton fl">Learn More <img     src="img/darkButtonArrow.png" alt="darkButtonArrow"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There are 4 li items. It works fine. But the problem is: whenever I start/reload the page it starts at the 4th list item instead of 1st. Also, it wraps around at 1st element, i.e; starting at 4th it travels 4th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 1st and then repeats the cycle. But it needs to be: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and repeat.
The jquery I am using is:

```
jQuery('#mainSlider').jcarousel({
    auto: 1,
    scroll: 1,   
    wrap: 'circular'  
});
```

Please someone help me regarding this matter.
Thanks.

Comment: you can set your start slide [using something like this](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/cookbook/custom-start-position.html)